# class template and functor

Tags: c++, templates

I have following class

```
class hash_key {
public:
    int get_hash_value(std::string &inStr, int inSize) const {
        int hash = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < (int)inStr.size(); i++)  {
            int val = (int)inStr[i];
            hash = (hash * 256 + val) % inSize;
        }
        return hash;
    }
};
```

I want to pass it to my another template class so that I can call `get_hash_value` 
how to do that is there any way to achieve the same using `operator()()`

Comment: Please use proper punctuation!

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Can't you just call `get_hash_value` from your class?

Comment: `get_hash_value()` should be static as it does not depend on `this`. Then you can use it as a regular function pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
class hash_key {
public:
    hash_key(std::string& inStr, int inSize) : size(inSize), str(inStr) {}
    int operator()() const
    {
        int hash = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < (int)str.size(); i++)  {
            int val = (int)str[i];
            hash = (hash * 256 + val) % size;
        }
        return hash;
    }

private:
   std::string str;
   int size;
};

Now you can do:

std::string str = "test";
hash_key key(str, str.size());

//pass below to template, calls `operator()()`
key();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct hash_key {
public:
    int operator()(std::string &inStr, int inSize) const {
        int hash = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < (int)inStr.size(); i++)  {
            int val = (int)inStr[i];
            hash = (hash * 256 + val) % inSize;
        }
        return hash;
    }
};
```